# Queries before submitting the iPhone project to App market

Tags: iphone, user-interface, reachability

I have made Map application to locate places in Australia. I am calling **web service** to fetch the places data and respective detail view. I have some doubts before launching the application to Australian app market.

- I have used Apples **Reachability** classes as it is for showing network/internet unavailability. Is this ok?? Or there is another method for this??
- I have used BSForwardGeocoder classes for forward geocoding. from link  http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/
- As I am using UIView to show detail view on annotation callout button by using addsubview method. I did not used navigation controller but still I am giving custom arrow back button on top of detail view

I am reading Human Interface guideline for iPhone application. Still I need suggestion from you. Am I doing right or do I need to change in above three condition. I dont want that my app get rejected by any of this reasons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)You have used apple reachability class,to check the network status,You can use that there is no issue with that,your app won't get rejected due to this.

2.)You have used BSForwardGeocoder for geocoding,I think there are no private api calls in this,but do check that is there any private api call.if there would be no Private api call.
There is no issue.So your app won't be rejected.

3.)You are using Views and showing your own arrows to pop and push,but you are not using any navigation controller.Thats fine,thats your own way to handle the views.That won't reject your app.

So cheers and go ahead,but do check that you dont use any private api call in your app.
as that is the maximum reason.

Hope This Will Help You........!

Comment: Thank you very much sabby. feeling good. I wll cross check with forward geocoder..

Comment: Welcome dear...well if my answer helped you then do checkmark....make it as accept answer,you will see a checkmark below the down arrow key here .....

Comment: add AppScanner scan to this and you are good to go http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner

Comment: Hi Sabby I have one doubt. Can you read point 7 on following link http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/      In my application I have check n/w status in if() condition and in else I have call Web URL. Is this correct??

Comment: If you are using the reachability classes to check your network is present or not,then its fine,they have provided the method to check if its 3G,WiFi and so on.And you are then making a call in the else condition to WS thats fine.But do check that if its working fine or not.Try to diable your network,then check that is this really making a call to your else part condition.

Comment: Ok..have you read the 7th point of this http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/...I got confused reading 7th point. Thats why I asked you again.

Comment: I have yet not submitted my app due to some other reason. I have one doubt here.... I have taken EULA textView screen with only one button title "I Agree" so that user can see this window atleast ones after installation of app. User can only use application when he press "I Agree" button. Is this ok with apple policy?

Comment: Yes thats fine...You can show the button to user to agree or disagree and in the case of disagree you can show the user some other window..which is eligible